# Deep interaction with break and catch

Tags: javascript

I'm having a little trouble writing a script.

I have a course structure that consists of several modules, and each module can have several lessons.

When the user enters the page, it needs to be defined which lesson will be selected for him to attend.

The business rule is: *select the first lesson that has not been viewed, and the module to which that lesson belongs. If they are all vieweds, select the first lesson of the first lesson.*

```js
const course = {
  title: 'Course name',
  duration: '1h 30min',
  modules: [
    {
      title: 'first module',
      lessons: [
        {
          title: 'lesson 1',
          viewed: true
        },
        {
          title: 'lesson 2',
          viewed: true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'second module',
      lessons: [
        {
          title: 'lesson 1',
          viewed: true
        },
        {
          title: 'lesson 2',
          viewed: false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'third module',
      lessons: [
        {
          title: 'lesson 1',
          viewed: false
        },
        {
          title: 'lesson 2',
          viewed: false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const selectedModule = {}
const selectedLesson = {}
```

i tried something like

```js
course.modules.find((module) => {
  return module.lessons.find((lesson) => {
    if (!lesson.viewed) {
      selectedModule = module
      selectedLesson = lesson

      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  })
})
```

but it doesn’t seem like a good solution, besides that I don’t do a `catch` if the `find` fails, then select the first lesson, from the first module.

What can I try next?

Comment: loop through your object recursively and return the lesson if it meets your criteria or call the next one if it doesnt

Comment: I don't understand what any of this has to do with break or catch?

Comment: `find` returns an object, don't use it to set properties like `selectedModule`. Just return them

Comment: @Liam if find the lesson that matches the criteria, should stop. if not found, enter catch

Comment: What's wrong with just using an `if` statement? It's really very unlcear what exactly your trying to do here.

Comment: You should not be setting variables inside of find. A for loop with find would actually make more sense than two finds nested.

Comment: @Liam `select the first lesson that has not been viewed, and the module to which that lesson belongs. If they are all vieweds, select the first lesson of the first lesson. ` isn't that clear enough?

sorry if i'm having trouble getting this, if it was clear to me, i wouldn't have come for help

Comment: @epascarello can you show an example of how it could be?

Comment: @YungSilva There are a lot of overly complex answers here in my opinion. I believe the cleanest way to solve your problem is by [using a reducer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63742089/3011431)

Comment: @Ollie Reduce does more iterations than are needed.  It does extra work.

Comment: @epascarello You are right, but in this example I think cleaner code would be much preferred over tiny performance enhancements.

Comment: It is personal opinion what is cleaner code. To me, code that exits out when it finds the correct thing is cleaner. That would be a simple loop. OP's code also works and exits out, personally that is not "clean" since that is not typically how find() works, but the code is efficient and exits out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution could work, but it is not the best thing to do. You just have to set the defaults at the start.

```js
const course = {
  title: 'Course name',
  duration: '1h 30min',
  modules: [{
      title: 'first module',
      lessons: [{
          title: 'lesson 1',
          viewed: true
        },
        {
          title: 'lesson 2',
          viewed: true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'second module',
      lessons: [{
          title: 'lesson 1',
          viewed: true
        },
        {
          title: 'lesson 2',
          viewed: false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'third module',
      lessons: [{
          title: 'lesson 1',
          viewed: false
        },
        {
          title: 'lesson 2',
          viewed: false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

let selectedModule = course.modules[0]
let selectedLesson = selectedModule.lessons[0]

course.modules.find((module) => {
  return module.lessons.find((lesson) => {
    if (!lesson.viewed) {
      selectedModule = module
      selectedLesson = lesson

      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  })
})

console.log(selectedModule.title, selectedLesson.title);
```

In your code, you are trying to do too much at one time. You need to break it up into a for loop which you can exit and a find which will look for the un-viewed lessons. You had the right idea, just do not use find() to set variables.

```js
 const course = {
  title: 'Course name',
  duration: '1h 30min',
  modules: [
    {
      title: 'first module',
      lessons: [
        {
          title: 'lesson 1',
          viewed: true
        },
        {
          title: 'lesson 2',
          viewed: true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'second module',
      lessons: [
        {
          title: 'lesson 1',
          viewed: true
        },
        {
          title: 'lesson 2',
          viewed: false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'third module',
      lessons: [
        {
          title: 'lesson 1',
          viewed: false
        },
        {
          title: 'lesson 2',
          viewed: false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


// set the default to first module and lesson
let selectedModule = course.modules[0];
let selectedLesson = selectedModule.lessons[0];

// loop over modules
for (const module of course.modules) {
  // look for lesson not viewed
  const unviewedLession = module.lessons.find(lesson => !lesson.viewed)
  // if new lesson, use that and exit
  if (unviewedLession) {
    selectedModule = module;
    selectedLesson = unviewedLession;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(selectedModule.title, selectedLesson.title);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this way:

- Find the **first incomplete module** i.e. module with at least one lesson unviewed.
- Get the unviewed lesson from the matched module.
- If all are viewed, find the **first module** with at least one lesson, get **first lesson** of it.

```
let x, y;
const incompleteModule = course.modules.find(module => module.lessons && module.lessons.length && module.lessons.some(({viewed}) => !viewed));

if (incompleteModule) {
    x = incompleteModule; 
    y = incompleteModule.lessons.find(({viewed}) => !viewed); 
} else {
    x = course.modules.find(module => module.lessons.length);
    y = x.lessons[0];
}
```

**Output for your sample data:**

```
{title: "second module", lessons: Array(2)}
{title: "lesson 2", viewed: false}
```

**When everything is set to viewed: true**

```
{title: "first module", lessons: Array(2)}
{title: "lesson 1", viewed: true}
```

Comment: No you have a logic problem. You used some where it should not be some

Comment: "incompleteModule" is a boolean in your code. Running it you will have `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined",`

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this

```
var module_and_lesson_loaded = 
  (course.modules.length>0 && course.modules.find((module))?
  course.modules.find((module) => {
   return (module.lessons.length>0 && module.lessons.find((lesson))?
    module.lessons.find((lesson) => {
    if (!lesson.viewed) {
      selectedModule = module
      selectedLesson = lesson

      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }):false;
}):false;

 if(module_and_lesson_loaded){
   //your code here
 }else{
   selectedModule = course.modules[0]
   selectedLesson = selectedModule.lessons[0]
 }
```

Well this might not be the right way I guess but it will check if those arrays are not empty and return a null if they are.

Answer (score 0):

Given your business rule:

> select the first lesson that has not been viewed, and the module to which that lesson belongs. If they are all vieweds, select the first lesson of the first lesson.

A [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) works perfectly here:

```js
// Loop through all modules and perform logic to determine the result
const result = course.modules.reduce((firstUnviewedLesson, currentModule) => {
  // If we already found the first unviewed lesson, return it
  if (firstUnviewedLesson) return firstUnviewedLesson
  
  // Attempt to find an unviewed lesson within the module
  const unviewedLesson = currentModule.lessons.find(lesson => lesson.viewed === false)

  // If it is found, create our custom object stating the module name and the title of the lesson
  if (unviewedLesson) {
    console.log('Found unviewed lesson')
    return {
      moduleTitle: currentModule.title,
      unviewedLesson: unviewedLesson.title
    }
  }
}, null)
```

After performing this logic, you can check if `result === null` - in this case it means that all lessons have been viewed and you can perform the second part of your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const course = {
  title: 'Course name',
  duration: '1h 30min',
  modules: [
    {
      title: 'first module',
      lessons: [
        {
          title: 'lesson 1',
          viewed: true
        },
        {
          title: 'lesson 2',
          viewed: true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'second module',
      lessons: [
        {
          title: 'lesson 1',
          viewed: true
        },
        {
          title: 'lesson 2',
          viewed: false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'third module',
      lessons: [
        {
          title: 'lesson 1',
          viewed: false
        },
        {
          title: 'lesson 2',
          viewed: false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const isEmpty = obj => {
    return (Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object);
    }

const findLesson = course => {
  let selected = {};
  course.modules.every(module => {
    if(!isEmpty(selected)) return;
    module.lessons.every(lesson => {
      if (lesson.viewed === false) {
        selected = {module: module.title, lesson: lesson.title};
        return;
      }
    });
  });
  return (isEmpty(selected)) ? {lesson: "lesson1", module: "first module"} : selected;
};

console.log(findLesson(course));
```

Comment: It is clean, only criticism is it loops more times than it needs to since there is no easy to exit forEach. BUT it selects the wrong module/lesson since you keep checking.

Comment: you are right, i reworked it to use .every instead of forEach

Answer (score 0):

The following approach intentionally makes use twice of [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Description). Thus it is most likely the only approach based on array methods that iterates the least possible steps. It immediately does exit both conditions at the same time, as soon as the first unvisited lesson was found.

The necessary module info is collected via an object which gets passed as the `this` context of both callback methods ...

```js
const course = {
  title: 'Course name',
  duration: '1h 30min',
  modules: [{
    title: 'first module',
    lessons: [{
      title: 'lesson 1',
      viewed: true
    }, {
      title: 'lesson 2',
      viewed: true
    }]
  }, {
    title: 'second module',
    lessons: [{
      title: 'lesson 1',
      viewed: true
    }, {
      title: 'lesson 2',
      viewed: false
    }]
  }, {
    title: 'third module',
    lessons: [{
      title: 'lesson 1',
      viewed: false
    }, {
      title: 'lesson 2',
      viewed: false
    }]
  }]
};


function assignModuleData(data, module, idx) {
  data.moduleTitle = module.title;
  data.moduleIdx = idx;
  data.module = module;
}
function assignLessonData(data, lesson, idx) {
  data.lessonTitle = lesson.title;    
  data.lessonIdx = idx;
  data.lesson = lesson;
}
function assignDefaultLesson(data, modules) {
  assignModuleData(data, modules[0], 0)
  assignLessonData(data, modules[0].lessons[0], 0)
}

function isUnviewedLessonAndWhichIsIt(lesson, idx) {
  const data = this;
  const isUnviewedLesson = !lesson.viewed;

  if (isUnviewedLesson) {
    assignLessonData(data, lesson, idx)
  }
  return isUnviewedLesson;
}
function isModuleWithUnviewedLessonAndWhichIsIt(module, idx, arr) {
  const data = this;

  assignModuleData(data, module, idx);
  const isModuleWithUnviewedLesson = module.lessons.some(isUnviewedLessonAndWhichIsIt, data);

  if ((idx >= (arr.length - 1)) && !isModuleWithUnviewedLesson) {
    assignDefaultLesson(data, arr);
  }
  return isModuleWithUnviewedLesson;
}


const nextLesson = {}

course.modules.some(isModuleWithUnviewedLessonAndWhichIsIt, nextLesson);

console.log(`"${ nextLesson.moduleTitle }, ${ nextLesson.lessonTitle }"`);
console.log(' nextLesson :', nextLesson);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```